# SHA2 Certificates in Windows 2003 CA

Tags: windows-server-2003, certificate, sha2

Is it possible to create a certificate template that uses SHA-2 (sha256, sha224, sha384, sha512), from a Windows server 2003 CA?

I know how to do it in Windows server 2008 based CA, with the new version (version 3) - it is possible to specify the hash algorithm (Under the "Cryptography" tab of the template properties). But is it possible in 2003 based CA?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/938397 will add SHA-2 support on a 2003 server. Don't know if certificate templates with SHA-2 can be created after applying this fix.

Answer (score 0):

OK. The support for SHA-2 was added on Vista (and Windows Server 2008)
So it's impossible...